# jQuery 1.5 vsdoc hack possible/advisable for Visual Studio intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, jquery-1.5

Until an official jQuery 1.5 vsdoc is available, does it work to just rename jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js to jquery-1.5-vsdoc.js and pull that into Visual Studio 2010? What kind of risks/faults might this create?

Comment: I found a couple of references to renaming the vsdoc file to make it work, so it looks like that aspect is viable: http://geekswithblogs.net/anirudha/archive/2011/01/20/how-to-play-with--jquery-1.5-beta-in-visual.aspx http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/536756.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a VSDoc available for 1.5: http://encosia.com/2011/02/04/a-vsdoc-for-jquery-1-5/

Comment: Many thanks, that's excellent! Also appreciate your blog post's reference to the vsdoc generator. http://damianedwards.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/jquery-vsdoc-file-generator/

Comment: I cannot get the 1.5 vsdoc working for 2008-- with or without the <para> tags. I posted a comment on Damian's blog, hopefully he has a fix. Anyone else run into this?

Comment: same issue here... my visual studio 2008 keeps crashing on me... it always seems to happen with the $("element").live(

Answer (score 2):

jQuery vsdoc File Generator for Visual Studio 2010

http://damianedwards.com/vsdoc/